# integration by parts for fractional laplacian formula for a larger class of functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration

When is this formula valid $\int_{\mathbb R^N} (-\Delta)^sf g =\int_{\mathbb R^N}  (-\Delta)^s g f $ with $s\in (0, 1)?$
I am aware of the integration by parts formula holds for $f, g$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^N)$. Is it valid for a larger class of functions which are not in $L^2$ but  $\int_{\mathbb R^N} (-\Delta)^sf g$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^N} (-\Delta)^sg f$ are finite.

Also see [integration by parts for the fractional Laplacian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129830/integration-by-parts-for-the-fractional-laplacian)

Comment: The formula is valid for $C_c^\infty$ functions, and then it can be extended continuously to $(f, g) \in \mathcal{D}_X \times \mathcal{D}_Y$ whenever $C_c^\infty$ is the core of $(-\Delta)^s$ on $X$ (with domain $\mathcal{D}_X$) and on $Y$ (with domain $\mathcal{D}_Y$), and $Y$ is continuously embedded into $X^*$ (perhaps with a weak* topology in $X^*$). Therefore, $X$ can be any of the $L^p$ spaces ($p \in (1, \infty)$), with $Y = X^*$, or a $C_0$ space, with, say, $Y = L^1$. Is that what you need? If yes, would you like a more detailed answer?

Comment: Thank for the help. Thats exactly what I was looking for.